# Is it possible to use older version software in 64bit version

Tags: go, x86-64, andlabs-ui

I am working with `go version go1.19.2 windows/amd64` on Windows7 and it is otherwise working very well.

I am trying to use [andlabs gui software](https://github.com/andlabs/ui) but I am getting following error:

```
# github.com/andlabs/ui
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

I did not build the andlabs package; I just used `go build` command after `go mod init` and `go mod tidy` commands. I am giving commands on Windows terminal opened in my source file directory.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Is it normal to use a "windows" version on Linux?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Windows7. I had written Linux by mistake. I have corrected it in the question above. The error is on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally means you have a C compiler installed for the underlying C code which does not have 64bit compiled in.
If you installed using MSYS2 make sure you opened the 64bit terminal window - there are 3 different ones for some reason…

Comment: I installed Go using `go1.19.2.windows-amd64.msi`. I also have Msys2 installed (I installed it to install Gtk which is still not  working for Go due to pkg-config errors). Above question errors are while working on Windows terminal. Will Andlabs  and Go work better in Msys2?

Comment: Msys2 installs its own terminal, it does not configure your windows terminal for use. You can do that manually but it won’t work out of the box. Run the msys2 64bit terminal and your commands will work.

Comment: Same code works all right on another desktop.

Comment: Then I would guess the other computer has the correct compiler setup?